# Proper GitHub workflow for issues

Tags: git, github

I'm looking for advice regarding a proper workflow on GitHub as it relates to the issues system.

Currently, I have a master branch that always only contains released software (it is tagged with the release number).  I maintain a changes branch (should be called `tobereleased`, so I'll use that name here).  When a release is performed, `tobereleased` matches `master`.  All features are made on branches from `tobereleased` and as each feature is completed, it is merged into `tobereleased` (actually, `tobereleased` is fast-forwarded to the tip of the feature branch because all feature branches are rebased to the new `tobereleased` branch) and work continues.

I enter issues using GitHub's issue system and I enter issue resolutions in the commit messages.  I notice that these commit messages appear in the issue thread, but the issues remain open.  Only when I perform a release do the issues get closed automatically as the code that resolved them is merged onto the master branch.

When I look at the issues, it's hard to tell what has been actually fixed without looking at them all - I'm not even sure how to filter on this.

I'm thinking of changing my workflow as follows:

1. Have `master` actually be the `tobereleased` branch, but with actual releases tagged with their release number and the zip for the releases in the release and on PyPI.
2. Let `master` be diverged from the zipped up release (for some reason I thought that was a bad idea).

In this way, pulling down the master branch becomes pulling down the "beta" release - after all, everything on the branch is `tobereleased` anyway, and has been tested, as such.  And the zipped up releases are there anyway.

Also, in this way, the issues would be shown as closed.  If anyone has the issue, but has actually released code, they would know to try the "beta" release currently on master.

It seems to me that's how GitHub was meant to operate.  Does anyone have any advice on this?

One more thing, the statistics shown for commits are also seen only for the master branch - again evidence that I should be doing what I'm proposing.